# How to add a custom rectangle drawing toolbox item in pdfium using c#?

Tags: c#, pdfium

I want to add a custom toolbox item in my windows form which will allow me to draw rectangular zones in the pdf(in the pdf viewer) and also get the co-ordinates of the zoned area automatically so that I can read the text from it and save it to a text file using PDFium. But I don't see any toolbox item in the PDFium dll to do this.

Can anyone show me how can this be done?

**Note:** I should also be able to do multiple zones(with different colors for different sections) and sequence them to my convenience.

Comment: Perhaps something like this could be useful: https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/115318/Controls-and-Libraries/PDF-Viewer/Examples/Miscellaneous/How-to-Custom-Draw-in-the-PDF-Viewer

Comment: @MikaalAnwar I was looking for a toolbar button type thing which I can click and simply draw a zone or multiple zones in the pdf, like you have in mspaint....can that be done